# What do these variables mean in regard to the wave equation and spherical waves?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, physics, wave-equation, spherical-harmonics

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Spherical_waves

Before it states ''where K=w/c'', there is an equation that has the following variables: d,r,w,c,l.

It also has f_lm(r)

What do each of the above mean in this case? I assume that c is the speed of the wave, r is the radial distance of the sphere and that d represents derivative?

Comment: $\omega$ angular frequency of wave, $c$ wave speed, the $d$'s are not variables but represent [derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative). $f_{lm}(r)$ are solutions to that equation, and $l$ and $m$ are indices denoting the various solutions (see [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics)).